# Trailing and leading commas added issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am calling a function from jsx as `xyz(id)` inside the `<img src = "xyz(id)" />`. In the calling function, I am retrieving the image value through a map as

```
const xyz = (id) =>{
     return abc.map(a => {
         if(a.id === id){
             if(a.url){
                 return a.url;
                 }
             }
         })
     }
```

When I inspect the img element trailing and leading commas are being appended after the return statement as "..returned_url..".

Comment: why is your function in quotes?

Comment: it is a typing error. sorry my bad

Answer (score 2):

You need to only return the url part to the caller if there's a match - you need to exclude the empty results from the `.map` callback, else they'll appear as empty strings between lots of commas.

```
const xyz = (id) => {
    return abc
        .map(a => {
            if (a.id === id && a.url) {
                return a.url;
            }
        })
        .filter(Boolean);
}
```

But returning an array when you're trying to set a `src` doesn't make much sense. If there's only one possible matching item, using `.find` might be more appropriate than `.map`, perhaps

```
const xyz = (id) => {
    return abc
        .find(a => a.id === id)
        ?.url;
}
```